# Retrieving a JSON string from Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, gson

I am working on an android application that uses Firebase Firestore as a database. I am trying to store a list of SoldItems where each soldItem has a PrescriptionType formed from Sealed classes.

```
data class SoldItem(var itemName : String = "",
                var quantity : String = "",
                var totalPrice : Int = 0,
                var itemQuantityType: ItemQuantityType = ItemQuantityType.SINGLE,
                var prescriptionType: String = ""
                ) : Serializable
```

prescriptionType while defined as a string is originally a Sealed Class PrescriptionType

```
sealed class PrescriptionType : Parcelable {
// Check how to parcelize objects
@Parcelize
data class Syrup(var quantityInMls : Double = 2.5, var frequency : PrescriptionFrequency = PrescriptionFrequency.Stat, var time : PrescriptionTime = PrescriptionTime.OneDay) : PrescriptionType()

@Parcelize
data class Lotion(var frequency : PrescriptionFrequency = PrescriptionFrequency.Stat, var time : PrescriptionTime = PrescriptionTime.OneDay): PrescriptionType()

@Parcelize
data class Capsule(var quantity : Int = 1, var frequency : PrescriptionFrequency = PrescriptionFrequency.Stat, var time : PrescriptionTime = PrescriptionTime.OneDay ) : PrescriptionType()}
```

I store prescriptionType as a string because of the lack of support in FirebaseFirestore android SDK directly for sealed classes. I've had to create my own TypeConverter. This works quite well in generating a string (JSON) from each prescriptionType and also generating a prescriptionType from the string.

```
@JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromPrescription(prescriptionType: PrescriptionType) : String{
        val prescriptionAdapterFactory : RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<PrescriptionType> = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.
                of(PrescriptionType::class.java, "type")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Syrup::class.java, "Syrup")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Lotion::class.java, "Lotion")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Capsule::class.java, "Capsule")

        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(prescriptionAdapterFactory).create()
        return "\"" +gsonBuilder.toJson(prescriptionType, PrescriptionType::class.java) + "\""
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toPrescriptionType(prescriptionType : String) : PrescriptionType {
        val prescriptionAdapterFactory : RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<PrescriptionType> = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.
                of(PrescriptionType::class.java, "type")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Syrup::class.java, "Syrup")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Lotion::class.java, "Lotion")
                .registerSubtype(PrescriptionType.Capsule::class.java, "Capsule")

        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(prescriptionAdapterFactory).create()
        return gsonBuilder.fromJson(prescriptionType, PrescriptionType::class.java)
    }
}
```

Storing the string works quite well in the database. The object is stored and everything is fine - we can see that the prescriptionType is a string.

[image: View in Firebase Firestore]

However in retrieving soldItems in Firebase, we encounter an issue where it seems the firebase SDK returns the JSON string and converts it to an object and hence crashes as prescriptionType is a String not an object.

```
val soldItemsType = object : TypeToken<List<SoldItem>>() {}.type
val soldItemsFromBackend = it.get("soldItems").toString()


Timber.d(soldItemsFromBackend)
val soldItems = Gson().fromJson<List<SoldItem>>(
                  soldItemsFromBackend,
                  soldItemsType
             )
```

Logging soldItemsFromBackend gives

```
[{drugQuantityType=SINGLE, prescriptionType={"type":"Capsule","frequency":"Stat","quantity":1,"time":"OneDay"}, itemName=Docusate, quantity=2, totalPrice=0}]
```

and trying to create soldItems using Gson gives an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 46 path $[0].prescriptionType
```

I think Gson wants to parse prescriptionType as a string but instead sees an object. I've tried to pad the prescriptionType string with extra quotes but it still didn't work.

Does anyone please know how I can retrieve prescriptionType as a string?

Comment: `val soldItemsFromBackend = it.get("soldItems").toString()` looks rather dubious. In case `get(...)` returns you a `List` then calling `toString()` on it does not give you valid JSON at all. So Firestore likely correctly returns a String, but your `toString()` call then calls `String.toString()` for `prescriptionType` which simply omits the quotes. Instead you should probably iterate over the SoldItem elements and only apply Gson to their `prescriptionType` JSON string.

Comment: @Marcono1234, thanks for your comment. it.get(...) does not return a list actually in this instance. It returns a type of Any?. Do you please know how I can retrieve soldItems as a list of SoldItems?

Comment: Can't you just cast it since apparently at runtime it is a list? Additionally what type does `it` have, or rather which method is `it.get(...)`? Is it `com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.get(...)`?